# Youtube iframe embed with webkit-transform scale on iOS

Tags: ios, iframe, webkit, youtube, css-transforms

I would have loved to use -webkit-transform scale() on an embedded youtube iframe for mobile users. But if you visit http://jsfiddle.net/tKbHz/9/ on iOS, there is some funkiness with the scaling of the iframe. This is not the case in Chrome or Desktop Safari (Mac). I believe I have found a bug within youtube - because other iframes seem to behave properly. Anyone experience this or know of a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the youtube video on mobile devices just go to the media player anyway?