# Potential iOS 7 scaling bug in iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, ios7

Effecting Safari in iOS 6 and 7 (possibly earlier as well).

When an `iframe` contains an element such as a `blockquote`, `iframe`, or `pre` tag, if that element has a width greater than the `iframe`'s size, it seems the whole content of the iframe is zoomed in... as in:

[image: Screenshot]

In both of these iframes the content is exactly the same:

```
<p>Some text.</p>
<blockquote>
    <p>Some more text.</p>
</blockquote>
```

But the CSS is slightly different (adding the width):

```
body {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    background: #DDF;
}
blockquote {
    background: red;
    margin: 0;
    width: 700px; /* V2 */
}
```

Can anyone confirm if this is a bug, with possible work around?

Example source code can be found at: http://www.krang.org.uk/misc/iFrame-iOS/

Might be related to: [Youtube iframe embed with webkit-transform scale on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12626080)

Comment: That sounds like might be by design.

Comment: If it was by design, wouldn't it be smaller? i.e. trying to show more of the object (not that I would want small text to become any smaller)... am curious to know the situations where this random scaling would be helpful :-)